# The size of the bytearray received to the client is different from that sent from the WCF service

Tags: arrays, vb.net, wcf, return, difference

I have a Self Hosted WCF service which is reading a big file with binaryreader and returning bytearray to client

Service splitting file as parts and 10MB per parts( 10485860 Bytes)

But client received 13981237 Bytes per parts, why is this difference.

This making my file is corrupt

This is my code from WCF

```
 myblocksize = 10485860
 my_bytearray = my_ibinaryreader.ReadBytes(myblocksize)
 my_ibinaryreader.Close()
 Return my_bytearray
```

and This is my client code

```
dim myWebClient as new WebClient
bytearray = myWebClient.DownloadData("SERVICEURL?file=bla.rar&currentPartNumber=myPartNumber")
```

and this is my WCF service full code

```
  Dim i As Integer = 0


        my_InStream = New System.IO.FileStream("d:\temp\" + File, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
        Dim my_ibinaryreader As System.IO.BinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(my_InStream)
        Dim my_splitArr As New ArrayList

        'Dim ofile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(File)

        Dim ofilesize As Long = my_ibinaryreader.BaseStream.Length

        Dim partcount As Integer = ofilesize \ 10485860

        If ofilesize Mod 10485860 <> 0 Then partcount += 1


        my_ibinaryreader.BaseStream.Position = currentPartNumber * 10485860
        Dim myblocksize As Long = 0
        Dim my_bytearray() As Byte

        If currentPartNumber = partcount - 1 Then
            myblocksize = ofilesize - (currentPartNumber * 10485860)
        Else
            myblocksize = 10485860
        End If

        my_bytearray = my_ibinaryreader.ReadBytes(myblocksize)
        my_ibinaryreader.Close()
        my_InStream.Close()
        Return my_bytearray
```

Comment: How does `my_bytearray` become `bla.rar`?

Comment: Service is receiving just filename bla.rar. Our files in server's d:\temp\ directory. So service is knows that file in d:\temp\bla.rar, reading file as bytes with binaryreader (10MB per part)

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli i added full service method code into my question

Comment: I still can't see how `my_bytearray` is transmitted or stored on the web

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli         Dim my_bytearray() As Byte

Comment: You've got a bytearray on the server side via WCF service. Then you download via web the bytearray via a web client. I'd like to know how the bytearray from the server ends up on the web and why.

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli writing bytearray into file please check my comment below

Answer (score -1):

@AlessandroMandelli writing bytearray into file with below code

First getting filesize from WCF that (example: 425000000 Byte - 435 MB)

and calculating partcount with filesize\104857600 (43 parts example)

and getting all parts with for statement

in WCF seeking by currentpart * 104857600

please check below code

```
dim myfileStream as filestream = new Filestream ("C:\aa.rar", filemode.create)

 dim partcount as integer = filesize \ 104857600

dim myWebClient as new WebClient

  for i as integer = 0 to partcount -1

       bytearray = myWebClient.DownloadData("SERVICEURL?file=bla.rar&currentPartNumber=myPartNumber")

    if not isnothing(byteArray) then

     myfileStream.Write(byteArray, 0 , byteArray.length)

     endif

next
```